# Fetching the result based on sourcetype

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I have written a query to fetch the all java exception count wise in splunk. But this query fetch across all sourcetype.

```
java.*.*Exception NOT warn  | rex "(?<rexexption>java*.*Exception)"| stats count by rexexption | table count,rexexption | sort count | reverse
```

Now I want all these exceptions per **sourcetype** wise.

Answer (score 0):

Go to you splunk home\main page and click on data summary.
There you can see source , sourcetype and other fields. just select one sourcetype which you want to go for and edit your query.

Source => path where logs are stored

sourcetype => log files

if you know your sourcetype name then edit your search :

```
sourcetype = java_*log*.txt java.*.*Exception NOT warn  | rex "(?<rexexption>java*.*Exception)"| stats count by rexexption | table count,rexexption | sort count | reverse
```